# How do I tether to a Nokia E61 mobile phone?

Tags: internet, connection, modem

I have a Nokia E61 mobile phone with 3G internet connection. When I connect it to the computer via USB cable and choose IP pasthrough, this line appears in the list of network connections:

Wired network (Nokia E61 (RNDIS))

This option is disabled, I can not choose it. What should I do to allow connection of the computer to the mobile phone as modem?

Update: the phone has Symbian S60 operating system.

Comment: Look through the phone's manual and see if there's any settings for sharing net access. Also, there's a tab on Network Manager called Mobile Broadband - look for your device there.

Comment: Might help to specify the OS that your phone is running.

Comment: Oxwivi, you are right - I have read the manual carefully and it helped.

Comment: The point was to choose PC suite mode on the phone instead of IP passthrough mode. It works well now. Thanks for great RTFM tip.

Answer (score 4):

The point was to choose PC suite mode on the phone instead of IP passthrough mode. It works well now.

Comment: I was desperate for this, thanks so much for posting the answer after solving the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the phone allow wired connections on other operating systems? Your carrier may have locked this down.

(Aside: My FreeRunner 'just worked' when I would hook it up to my computer to charge it; it was detected as an ethernet card.)